# Regex to Match Specific URL JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm trying to match a specific URL(http://www.example.me/area/?si=) that allows me to get value from si. si value will be dynamic

http://www.example.me/area/?si=4077765

Comment: are you trying to get query string value?

Comment: or are you trying to check the query string `si` is there or not?

Comment: he said "that allows me to get the value from the si"

Comment: At least own up to your downvote. Please explain.

Comment: Check [how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter) which you've pretty much duplicated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Something like that can do the trick I think:

```
var regex = /http\:\/\/www\.example\.me\/area\/\?si=(\w*)/;

var url = 'http://www.example.me/area/?si=4077765';
var si = url.match(regex)[1]; // si = '4077765'
```

The first part of the regex is simply your URL "\" is used to escape special characters.

(\d+) is a capturing group that matches all character from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character from 0 to n iteration.

Comment: why the downvote? Who is downvoting everything without an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the value of the `si` key in the query string will always be digits (ie: 0 - 9), try this...

```
var url = 'http://www.example.me/area/?test=4894&si=4077765&f=fjjjf',
    si = url.match(/.*[\?&]si=(\d+)/i)[1];
```

or a little more generic...

```
function getQueryStringValue(url, key) {
    var regex = new RegExp('.*[\\?&]' + key + '=(\\d+)', 'i');
    return url.match(regex)[1];
}
```

if not digits try this...

```
/.*[\?&]si=(\w+)/i
```

**Explanation:**

- .* matches any character (except newline) between 0 and unlimited times
- [\?&] match a single character, either ? or &
- si= matches the characters si= literally (case insensitive)
- (\d+) first capturing group. matches any digit [0-9] between 1 and unlimitted times
- i modifier - case insensitive

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gT8bU6/1)

Comment: Without an explanation of the regex, this answer is worthless. Please fix.

Answer (score -1):

**Get any query string value**

`function qstr(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
            return pair[1];
        }
    }
    return false;
}`

**Check Query String Exists**

`function isset_qstr(field) {
    var url = vp_furl();
    if (url.indexOf('?' + field + '=') != -1) {
        return true;
    } else if (url.indexOf('&' + field + '=') != -1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}`

I think you need the first function. Vote up if you think its helpful.

Thank you. Good Luck